How can I make sure that a variable in my REGEX gets interpreted as a literal string, but at the same time also using other special characters?
This is a line from my Bash shell script:
found_line=$(echo "${contents_file}" | grep  "^${char}")

What I want to happen is to get al the lines where the line starts with my variable "char". But here is the problem, I want my variable to be treated as a literal string, because when my char is a '.' it gets treated as a wildcard and that's not what I want to happen. I want it to work with every single character.
I know that you can use the -F flag with grep to match the literal string but then my "^" anchor also gets interpreted as a literal string which is not good. I also thought about escaping my char variable but this also wouldnt work because char could be '1' and then it would be refering to a captured group.
So how can I achieve this functionality?

Sounds like an X and Y problem...

I think you will probably have to use awk.

if char is only one character, you can escape it '['"$char"']'

please update the question with the output from typeset -p contents_file char; if contents_file is large then for demonstration purposes cut it down to 5-6 lines (at no more than 15-20 chars per line), making sure you have a mix of lines that match and do not match for a couple different versions of char that you're looking to address

@StefanHegny you can escape it, but not like that as it won't work for all characters, e.g. ^. Try, for example, echo '^' | grep '[^]' and see is-it-possible-to-escape-regex-metacharacters-reliably-with-sed.

The line found_line=$(echo "${contents_file}" | grep  "^${char}") being present in your shell script means there are probably bigger issues than the problem you're asking about as a) you're apparently reading the contents of a file into a variable, b) you're probably using some kind of shell read loop, c) you're spawning a subshell unnecessarily, d) you're using echo instead of printf, etc. You may want to post your script on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ to get feedback on it.

Assuming you want all lines in file file that start with the literal $char, with awk:
awk -v s="$char" 'index($0, s) == 1' file


My datafiles:
$: cat charfile
a
1
.
$
[
]
\
-
x

$: cat txt
foo
alpha
1 number
.dot
2 not used
$dolla

^The above line is *empty*
[ open
] close
\ backslash
- a dash
x all good.

my simplistic script, which isn't even verifying there's a newline on the last line -
$: cat tst
#! bash -x
while read -r c; do grep "^[$c]" txt; done < charfile

The output:
$: ./tst
+ read -r c
+ grep '^[a]' txt
alpha
+ read -r c
+ grep '^[1]' txt
1 number
+ read -r c
+ grep '^[.]' txt
.dot
+ read -r c
+ grep '^[$]' txt
$dolla
+ read -r c
+ grep '^[[]' txt
[ open
+ read -r c
+ grep '^[]]' txt
] close
+ read -r c
+ grep '^[\]' txt
\ backslash
+ read -r c
+ grep '^[-]' txt
- a dash
+ read -r c
+ grep '^[x]' txt
x all good.
+ read -r c

This works because I enclosed the pattern in double-quotes, which interpolate the variable, but until the resulting string gets passed to grep it's not using the metacharacters. The square-brackets create a quoted character set, so the metacharacters read are NOT treated as metacharacters. In a more complicated example it would probably fail.
That might be version dependent, you should check... but Renaud's awk solution is probably safer.

Try adding ^ to your charfile :-). ^ is still a metacharacter inside a bracket expression, it needs to be escaped by a preceding \ to become literal, i.e. \^ instead of [^].

There's that more complicated example! Knew I missed something, lol

apparently just trying to match this byte (^) at the start of a row is really hectic :

ggrep := gnu-grep
 grep := bsd-grep


   grep -e | ^\^
     1  ^

   grep -e | ^[^]
     1  grep: brackets ([ ]) not balanced

   grep -e | ^[\^]
     1  \
     2  ^

   grep -e | ^[\\^]
     1  \
     2  ^

   grep -e | ^\136
     1  grep: invalid backreference number

   grep -e | ^[\136]
     1  1
     2  3
     3  6
     4  \

   grep -e | ^\x5E
     1  ^

   grep -e | ^[\x5E]
     1  5
     2  E
     3  \
     4  x

   grep -e | ^\x{5E}
     1  ^

   grep -e | ^[\x{5E}]
     1  5
     2  E
     3  \
     4  x
     5  {
     6  }


   grep -E | ^\^
     1  ^

   grep -E | ^[^]
     1  grep: brackets ([ ]) not balanced

   grep -E | ^[\^]
     1  \
     2  ^

   grep -E | ^[\\^]
     1  \
     2  ^

   grep -E | ^\136
     1  grep: invalid backreference number

   grep -E | ^[\136]
     1  1
     2  3
     3  6
     4  \

   grep -E | ^\x5E
     1  ^

   grep -E | ^[\x5E]
     1  5
     2  E
     3  \
     4  x

   grep -E | ^\x{5E}
     1  ^

   grep -E | ^[\x{5E}]
     1  5
     2  E
     3  \
     4  x
     5  {
     6  }


  ggrep -e | ^\^
     1  ^

  ggrep -e | ^[^]
     1  ggrep: Unmatched [, [^, [:, [., or [=

  ggrep -e | ^[\^]
     1  \
     2  ^

  ggrep -e | ^[\\^]
     1  \
     2  ^

  ggrep -e | ^\136
     1  ggrep: Invalid back reference

  ggrep -e | ^[\136]
     1  1
     2  3
     3  6
     4  \

  ggrep -e | ^\x5E
     1  ggrep: warning: stray \ before x

  ggrep -e | ^[\x5E]
     1  5
     2  E
     3  \
     4  x

  ggrep -e | ^\x{5E}
     1  ggrep: warning: stray \ before x

  ggrep -e | ^[\x{5E}]
     1  5
     2  E
     3  \
     4  x
     5  {
     6  }


  ggrep -E | ^\^
     1  ^

  ggrep -E | ^[^]
     1  ggrep: Unmatched [, [^, [:, [., or [=

  ggrep -E | ^[\^]
     1  \
     2  ^

  ggrep -E | ^[\\^]
     1  \
     2  ^

  ggrep -E | ^\136
     1  ggrep: Invalid back reference

  ggrep -E | ^[\136]
     1  1
     2  3
     3  6
     4  \

  ggrep -E | ^\x5E
     1  ggrep: warning: stray \ before x

  ggrep -E | ^[\x5E]
     1  5
     2  E
     3  \
     4  x

  ggrep -E | ^\x{5E}
     1  ggrep: warning: stray \ before x

  ggrep -E | ^[\x{5E}]
     1  5
     2  E
     3  \
     4  x
     5  {
     6  }


  ggrep -P | ^\^
     1  ^

  ggrep -P | ^[^]
     1  ggrep: missing terminating ] for character class

  ggrep -P | ^[\^]
     1  ^

  ggrep -P | ^[\\^]
     1  \
     2  ^

  ggrep -P | ^\136
     1  ^

  ggrep -P | ^[\136]
     1  ^

  ggrep -P | ^\x5E
     1  ^

  ggrep -P | ^[\x5E]
     1  ^

  ggrep -P | ^\x{5E}
     1  ^

  ggrep -P | ^[\x{5E}]
     1  ^

